# Strong property in ARC - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties, automatic-ref-counting, null

My question is simple but though I didn't found a precise answer on the net.
Do I have to set to nil a strong property in viewDidUnload method ?

I know weak property will be automatically set to nil but what about strong property? Do I have to do this in viewDidUnload and also in didReceiveMemoryWarning ?

Thank you a lot!
Teddy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set it to nil in the "companion" function to where it is set, or where you want it to go away.  For instance, if you set it in `viewDidLoad` you typically set it to nil in `viewDidUnload`.  If you set it in `viewWillAppear` then set it to nil in `viewWillDisappear`.

Set it to nil in `didReceiveMemoryWarning` if it is something that you don't really need and can be recreated when you do need it next.  (such as variables automatically created in their getter's).

Comment: Just to be sure, I MUST set a strong property to nil right? If I don't memory will not be free?